# using amp-video inside amp-lightbox

Tags: html, amp-html

I have the specification load load a modal window with a video using `amp-html`.

We are trying to achieve this using `amp-lightbox` with a `amp-video` inside the modal window. However, the video is not responding to the size of the modal window (I assume this is down to the initial `display:none` on the lightbox when the page is loaded).

I have the following `amp-html`;

```
<a class="travel-results-result-link block relative" on="tap:video-1">
    <amp-img class="block rounded" width="346" height="200" noloading="" src="/images/video/image01.jpg"></amp-img>
</a>

//...

<amp-lightbox id="video-1" layout="nodisplay">
    <div class="lightbox"
         on="tap:video-1.close"
         role="button"
         tabindex="0">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <amp-video controls
                           width="320" height="240"
                           layout="responsive"
                           poster="images/video/image01.jpg">
                           <source src="videos/gail-video-1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                           <div fallback>
                               <p>This browser does not support the video element.</p>
                           </div>
                </amp-video>
            </div>
     </div>
</amp-lightbox>
```

The css for my modal body is simply;

```
    .modal-body {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 90%;
        margin-top: 75px;
        height: calc(100% - 200px);
    }
```

When I click to load the modal both the preload image and video are loading outside the boundaries of the modal-body div? can anyone suggest a way around this?

Comment: what happens if you move `class=lightbox` from the `<div>` to `<amp-lightbox>`? An alt idea is to use amp-image-lightbox and reassign the `<a>` structure to amp-image-lightbox .

Comment: thanks for the idea, I'll give it a go a revert back shortly

Comment: as an update unfortunately neither of the above worked. amp-image-lightbox worked for img but as soon as I referenced amp-video nothing happened.

Comment: don't mean to sound condescending here, but ... have you loaded all requires libs? We have an amp-image-lightbox that is a thumbnail for an amp-video with a youtube source and it works as expected.